# DatePicker Does Not Respect Form Reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik

I have an asp.net form with various textboxes and kendo datepickers.   I allow the user to fill in the form and if they decide to start again I have a reset button for them.

The reset button should reset the form to its original model data.  To be clear I don't want to reset the form to blank values, I want to reset all the inputs to their original model values.

This works nicely for the textboxes however after hitting the reset button the datepicker simply displays a "d" and not the original model value.

I use the following javascript/jquery to reset the form:

```
$(this).closest('form')[0].reset();
```

Here is my extract form code with the datepicker:

```
<tr>
    <td><label asp-for="Aircraft.SerialNumber" class="frm-label"></label></td>
    <td>
        <input asp-for="Aircraft.SerialNumber" autocomplete="off" class="k-textbox k-state-disabled" style="width:400px" disabled />
        <span asp-validation-for="Aircraft.SerialNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label asp-for="Aircraft.ManufactureDate" class="frm-label"></label> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <kendo-datepicker name="DatePicker" for="Aircraft.ManufactureDate" class=""  style='width: 400px;' />
        <span asp-validation-for="Aircraft.ManufactureDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm not sure wether this problem lies with the telerik widget or my jquery/javascript code so I have also posted [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/datepicker-does-not-respect-javascript-form-reset)

Answer (score 1):

I tried with code sample :https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/datepicker/tag-helper

And using :

```
$("#FormID").trigger("reset");
```

It can successfully reset datetimepicker to default model value :

```
  <kendo-datepicker name='datepicker'
                      for="OrderDate" 
                      style='width: 100%;'></kendo-datepicker>
```

But not work for datetimepicker which set with static value(change to format string) :

```
  <kendo-datepicker name="monthpicker"
                      start="CalendarView.Year"
                      depth="CalendarView.Year"
                      format="MMMM yyyy"
                      value='DateTime.Parse("November 2011")'
                      style="width: 100%;"></kendo-datepicker>
```

But you can always set the value for that(store value form model/viewbag in hidden field) :

```
$("#monthpicker").val("November 2013")
```

EDIT :

So as a workaround , you can add hidden field :

```
<input type="hidden" id="DeOrderDate" asp-for="OrderDate"/>
```

And then use Jquery to re-bind the value :

```
$("#FormID").trigger("reset");
$("#OrderDate").data('kendoDatePicker').value($("#DeOrderDate").val())
```

That should work for special scenario .

Comment: Sorry I thought this worked, but there was an error in my testing.  Using the code you have provided does the same thing for me it simply resets the datepicker to the value "d" and not the original model value.

Comment: I checked the sample application you suggested and it works as you described.  The difference between mine and the sample application is that my model is annotated with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]public DateTime ManufactureDate { get; set; }` removing this fixed the problem but I cant figure out why.  Also changing the format string to "dd/MM/yyyy" also stuffs it up.

Comment: @Reafidy  Not sure , or you can try the workaround as my edited reply

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure your workaround is suitable.   I have up to 100 datepickers on one page generated dynamically.  I will look into it though.   It seems when the format is changed the datepicker overrides the "value" attribute with the format so you end up with `value="dd/MM/yyyy"`.  So the reset reverts to this.  Seems odd.